# How do I find text after a given key word?

Tags: python

I am practicing my programming skills (in Python) and I realized that I don't know what to do when I need to find a value that is unknown but introduced by a key word. I am taking the information for this off a website where in the page source it says, '"size":"10","stockKeepingUnitId":"(random number)"' 
How can I figure out what that number is. 
This is what I have so far --

def stock():

```
global session
endpoint = '(website)'
reponse = session.get(endpoint)
soup = bs(response.text, "html.parser")
sizes = soup.find('"size":"10","stockKeepingUnitId":')
```

Comment: `split()` on the colon and go from there? So `my_string.split(':')` and see what it gives with `print()`

Comment: Please provide code that is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of the question you are trying to ask

Comment: Where are you trying to find this? It looks like you may be trying to parse RFC822-style headers, in which case there's a library for that, and using that library is definitely the best way to do it. If it's in a quoted string in the middle of some text, as in your question, you probably instead want to extract all the quoted strings and check if each one `startswith('content: ')`. If it's just randomly interspersed in some text, you probably want to `re.findall` a pattern like `content:\s\"(\d+)\"`. Or maybe you're trying to parse some JavaScript source and it's part of an object assignment…

Comment: @roganjosh 'content: "67588978" is not a correct string in python, also he calls 'content' a key word, which seems to me like he's probably using a dictionary, but it could be a string who knows. He needs to provide code before any of us can say anything with some certainty.

Comment: @bigwillydos not gonna disagree with that. I'm taking a small step into the unknown to assume that there's actually a valid string, or should we just be close-voting right now?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: It is not a string but rather from a website code

Comment: @bigwillydos _now_ I've voted unclear because a reasonable answer gets knocked back. OP: please see how to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

Off the top of my head there are two ways to do this. Say you have the string `mystr = 'some text...content:"67588978"'`. The first way is just to search for `"content:"` in the string and use string slicing to take everything after it:

```
num = mystr[mystr.index('content:"') + len('content:"'):-1]
```

Alternatively, as probably a better solution, you could use regular expressions

```
import re
nums = re.findall(r'.*?content:\"(\d+)\"')
```

As you haven't provided an example of the dataset you're trying to analyze, there could also be a number of other solutions. If you're trying to parse a JSON or YAML file, there are simple libraries to turn them into python dicts (`json` is part of the standard library, and [PyYaml](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) handles YAML files easily).

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information - I can not split it because I do not know what the number is. The number is provided by a website, and they change it per product.

Comment: You don't need to know the number itself - just the text surrounding it